# img,button tag rendered different in ff and safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, safari

I have  problem that i can not seem to fix on my own.

EDIT, to the real problem.

The button tag is rendered differently in FF and Safari.
In chrome the button has no extra hidden padding or margins.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh978a7k/1/)

The image  in chrome is nice and evenly distributed and fills all element(red borded), no white space is left anywhere.

Safari it leaves left side space.
in firefox it leaves left side and top some space.

How do i target button tag for safari/ffox specifically and fix the issue?

CSS

```
.vlp_s_container {
    position: relative;
    /* height: 132px; */
    border: 1px solid red; 
/*  background-color: yellow; */
    width:206px;
}
/* Zoom In #1 */
.vlp_s_hover01 .vlp_s_fig .vlp_s_img {
/*  padding: 0px; */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.vlp_s_hover01 .vlp_s_fig:hover .vlp_s_img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.vlp_s_button {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: normal;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vlp_s_button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vlp_s_img {
    width: 206px;
    height: 116px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}

.vlp_s_fig {
    width: 206px;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="vlp_s_container" title="Watch This"
            id="abc">
            <div class="vlp_s_hover01 vlp_s_column">
                <figure class="vlp_s_fig">

                    <div>
                        <button class="vlp_s_button">
                            <img class="vlp_s_img"
                                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Jenson_Button_2014_Singapore_FP2.jpg">
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post some code, please.

Comment: updated the question with code.

Comment: Could you please provide the generated HTML code and the CSS styles only? It would be easier for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If one inspects the page i think the structure is  very clear to see, and the Css posted above is the css used to style the  problematic boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Firefox has its own padding and margins to `<button>` tag and using this  css works to fix the problem for firefox

CSS

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```